# Creating HTML table without using a table tag

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a table without using the `table` tag, only using the `display: table` properties in CSS. But somehow, the rows are not getting properly aligned. The widths of the cells vary. The cells of the first row have different widths from the cells of the other rows. 
Here is the JSFiddle for a clear understanding : http://jsfiddle.net/tryouts/3MVUD/

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <header>
        <span class="title">Title</span>
        <span class="avail">Avail</span>
        <span class="list">List</span>
    </header>
    <main>
       <section id="item-1">
            <span class="title">Item 1</span>
            <span class="avail"></span>
            <span class="list">
                <span>One</span>
                <span>Two</span>
                <span>Three</span>
                <span>Four</span>
            </span>
       </section> 
       <section id="item-2">
            <span class="title">Item 2</span>
            <span class="avail">Yes</span>
            <span class="list">
                <span>Two</span>
                <span>Three</span>
            </span>
       </section> 
       <section id="item-3">
            <span class="title">Item 3</span>
            <span class="avail"></span>
            <span class="list">
            </span>
       </section>         
    </main>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
div.content {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

div.content header, div.content main section {
    display: table-row;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

span.title,span.avail,span.list {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 33%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I do not want to change the existing HTML content, that's the main reason for using CSS to create a table like structure.

Comment: what the problem in your current output?

Comment: The widths of the cells vary. You can check the jsfiddle link.

Comment: What is the purpose of this exercise? Why don't you use a table tag?

Comment: If it's tabular data, why not use the `<table>` tag instead of hacking other elements to behave like a table?

Comment: Because, as he says, he can't change the HTML so is using CSS to change the appearance without having to change the content.

Comment: @benl2k, he says he doesn't *want to*, not that he *can't*... :)

Comment: Regardless of can't or won't, telling him to change his HTML doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Yes it doesn't answer the question per se, but it would be a lot easier, and save time if the correct markup was used for the content..

Comment: Changing the HTML involves a chain of a other changes, which itself is a lot of work and hence the hack. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to add:

```
main { display: table-row-group }
```